# Error sending message, child exited 71 (Operating system error)

Tags: shell-script, mutt

I'm trying to send mail through mutt command. I got the error message **Error sending message, child exited 71 (Operating system error.)**.

I was able to send email through this command earlier, but can't now.
I don't know why it happen. I tried searching on Google but not got any appropriate answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `mutt -d 2` and look at the generated `~/.muttdebug*` file. Does that provide any helpful hints? (-d sets debug output level. Up to `-d 5` is allowed, according to the man page for my mutt.)

Comment: I am getting error while trying command **DEBUG was not defined during compilation.  Ignored.** could provide example, How to use **mutt -d 2**

Comment: So your mutt was compiled without debug support. Pity. Can you send any mail at all through mutt?

Comment: Currently I am unable to send mail through **mutt**.

Comment: What distribution you are running? If you run a debian-like OS, you should install `mutt-dbg` to get debugging symbols, if it's a RPM-based you should run as root `debuginfo-install mutt`. Other distros has different methods. Once you do this run `mutt -d 2` again.